# Restore file on failed move?

Tags: files, nemo

I'm running a recent Linux Mint and tried to move a file within the same mount using Cut and Paste in Nemo (file manager).
Although there was a file with the same file name already present in the destination directory, nothing happened (e.g. no "overwrite?" dialog) -- except the source file is now gone.
Trying to "undo" the action, a dialog with IO error appeared.

Is there a way to restore the source file?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Nemo, what dialogue did you expect to see? You appear to say that the file was successfully moved, if so, what is the issue? If you want to move it back, can't you do a similar operation again?

Comment: @Kusalananda Another file with the same name was present in the destination, which usually should result in an "overwrite?" dialog - but nothing happened, except the source file vanished (data loss!?).

Comment: I doubt the file was lost. It sounds more as if the file was moved to some unexpected location. Can you search for the file's name with Nemo? If you have a terminal handy, you could try `find ~ -name 'name-of-file'` (where `name-of-file` is either the _complete and exact_ name of the file or a filename globbing pattern that should match the name).

Comment: You mention some error message. What did the error message say, exactly?

Comment: If there was a file with the same name at the destination, how do you know it didn't get overwritten by the source file? How do you know that Nemo didn't perform the operation without the dialog (due to a change of configuration, a bug, or even just you accidentally pressing "enter" before the dialog appeared)?